# Calculating X & Y coordinates of a point offset from an ellipse at a given polar angle and intersecting point

Tags: conic-sections, polar-coordinates

I am using the following equations to identify the x and y coordinates of a point on an ellipse at polar angle θ.

$x=\pm\cfrac{ab}{\sqrt{b^2+a^2 (\tan^2\theta)}}$

$y=\pm\cfrac{ab}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2 (\tan^2\theta)}}$

Perpendicular to this point on the ellipse I would like to calculate the X and Y coordinates at an outside offset distance of d.

Effectively, I am trying to identify points on a parallel curve to the ellipse.

Any and all assistance is much appreciated!

Comment: it is not just solve $\vec{x}\vec{q}=0$? (x are the vectors given in the question..)

Comment: Thank you for the quick response.  I apologize, but I do not understand your equation above.  Can you please give an example, or perhaps elaborate a bit further?

Comment: you have a vector $\vec{x}=(x,y)$ and you wan to find a vector which is perpendicular to it.  Therefore you know that the scalar product of this unknown vector $\vec{q}$ has to fullfil the condtion $\vec{x}^t\cdot \vec{q}=0$ where $t$ stands for "transpose" and $\cdot $ indicates the usual scalar product.

Comment: Furthermore, to fix the unknown vector uniquely you will need a second condition as  $||\vec{q}||=1$ or something like that

Comment: Thank you tired for all of your help so far... I have tried to wrap my brain around what you've presented but I am still not there...  Can we work with the following example?  Major axis = 10, Minor axis = 5, θ = 30° d = 1... using the equations above x = 3.2733 y = 1.8898.  This is the point that lies on the ellipse.  Can you use these numbers and solve for the X/Y coordinates (d=1) perpendicular from that point on the ellipse?  Thank you again for your help!

Comment: i don't have time today, but you might find the result which you might want to get in end here:
http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Ellipse.html

Look at the last paragraph!

Comment: Thank you tired for all of your help on this!  That last paragraph contained the key.  I was able to identify the perpendicular point in space I was looking for by working through 4 seperate equations.  I would answer my own question, however I will probably butcher the response.  As I am new to the forum, should I just delete my question in place of answering it?  Thank you again for everything!